# Applitools integration with WebdriverIO

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webdriver-io, applitools

I am trying to integrate Applitools with WebdriverIO project. The details are below:

- node version: v12.18.2
- npm version: 6.14.5
- wdio version: 6.3.6

My `wdio` file has a service like below:

```
services: ['selenium-standalone'],
```

Next I installed applitools with command:
`npm install '@applitools/eyes.webdriverio' --save-dev`. Now, when I run the project using `npm run test`, I am getting the following error:

```
    > webdriverio-applitools_1@1.0.0 test D:\WebDriverIO\WebDriverIo-Applitools_1
> wdio wdio.conf.js


Execution of 1 spec files started at 2020-08-04T11:33:02.577Z

2020-08-04T11:33:02.725Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onPrepare hook
2020-08-04T11:33:04.515Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onWorkerStart hook
2020-08-04T11:33:04.518Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Start worker 0-0 with arg: wdio.conf.js
[0-0] 2020-08-04T11:33:04.903Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Run worker command: run
[0-0] 2020-08-04T11:33:04.911Z INFO webdriverio: Initiate new session using the ./protocol-stub protocol
[0-0] RUNNING in chrome - D:\WebDriverIO\WebDriverIo-Applitools_1\main\visual.js
[0-0] 2020-08-04T11:33:06.448Z INFO webdriverio: Initiate new session using the webdriver protocol
[0-0] 2020-08-04T11:33:06.449Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/session
[0-0] 2020-08-04T11:33:06.450Z INFO webdriver: DATA {
  capabilities: {
    alwaysMatch: { browserName: 'chrome', acceptInsecureCerts: true },
    firstMatch: [ {} ]
  },
  desiredCapabilities: { browserName: 'chrome', acceptInsecureCerts: true }
}
[0-0] 2020-08-04T11:33:09.975Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND getTitle()
[0-0] 2020-08-04T11:33:09.975Z INFO webdriver: [GET] http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/session/4e3081702a2e0e07eba23d42fa81fce4/title
[0-0] Title of page is [object Promise]
[0-0] 2020-08-04T11:33:09.980Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND navigateTo("https://applitools.com/helloworld")
[0-0] 2020-08-04T11:33:09.980Z INFO webdriver: [POST] http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/session/4e3081702a2e0e07eba23d42fa81fce4/url
2020-08-04T11:33:09.980Z INFO webdriver: DATA { url: 'https://applitools.com/helloworld' }
[0-0] TypeError in "my first visual test should look visually perfect"
browser.getViewportSize is not a function
[0-0] 2020-08-04T11:33:09.988Z INFO webdriver: COMMAND deleteSession()
[0-0] 2020-08-04T11:33:09.988Z INFO webdriver: [DELETE] http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/session/4e3081702a2e0e07eba23d42fa81fce4
[0-0] 2020-08-04T11:33:09.997Z INFO webdriver: RESULT
[0-0] FAILED in chrome - D:\WebDriverIO\WebDriverIo-Applitools_1\main\visual.js
2020-08-04T11:33:12.348Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onComplete hook
2020-08-04T11:33:12.349Z INFO @wdio/selenium-standalone-service: shutting down all browsers

 "spec" Reporter:
------------------------------------------------------------------
[chrome 84.0.4147.105 windows #0-0] Spec: D:\WebDriverIO\WebDriverIo-Applitools_1\main\visual.js
[chrome 84.0.4147.105 windows #0-0] Running: chrome (v84.0.4147.105) on windows
[chrome 84.0.4147.105 windows #0-0] Session ID: 4e3081702a2e0e07eba23d42fa81fce4
[chrome 84.0.4147.105 windows #0-0]
[chrome 84.0.4147.105 windows #0-0] my first visual test
[chrome 84.0.4147.105 windows #0-0]    ✖ should look visually perfect
[chrome 84.0.4147.105 windows #0-0]
[chrome 84.0.4147.105 windows #0-0] 1 failing (2.2s)
[chrome 84.0.4147.105 windows #0-0]
[chrome 84.0.4147.105 windows #0-0] 1) my first visual test should look visually perfect
[chrome 84.0.4147.105 windows #0-0] browser.getViewportSize is not a function
[chrome 84.0.4147.105 windows #0-0] TypeError: browser.getViewportSize is not a function
[chrome 84.0.4147.105 windows #0-0]     at Context.<anonymous> (D:\WebDriverIO\WebDriverIo-Applitools_1\main\/visual.js:15:42)
[chrome 84.0.4147.105 windows #0-0]     at Context.executeAsync (D:\WebDriverIO\WebDriverIo-Applitools_1\node_modules\@wdio\utils\build\shim.js:123:21)
[chrome 84.0.4147.105 windows #0-0]     at Context.testFrameworkFnWrapper (D:\WebDriverIO\WebDriverIo-Applitools_1\node_modules\@wdio\utils\build\test-framework\testFnWrapper.js:49:28)


Spec Files:      0 passed, 1 failed, 1 total (100% completed) in 00:00:09

2020-08-04T11:33:12.353Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Shutting down spawned worker
2020-08-04T11:33:12.603Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Waiting for 0 to shut down gracefully
2020-08-04T11:33:12.604Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: shutting down
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! webdriverio-applitools_1@1.0.0 test: `wdio wdio.conf.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the webdriverio-applitools_1@1.0.0 test script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\soham\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-08-04T11_33_12_626Z-debug.log
```

I have a test case that looks like this:

```
const {Eyes, Target} = require('@applitools/eyes.webdriverio');
const eyes = new Eyes();
eyes.setApiKey('API KEY');

describe('my first visual test', function () {
    it('should look visually perfect', async function () {
        browser.url('./helloworld');

        const pageTitle = browser.getTitle();

        console.log(`Title of page is ${pageTitle}`)

        
        try {
            //const viewportSize = browser.getViewportSize();
    
            await eyes.open(browser, 'Hello World!', 'My first Javascript test!');

            await eyes.check('Main Page', Target.window());

            browser.click('button');

            await eyes.check('Click!', Target.window());

            await eyes.close();
        } finally {
            await eyes.abortIfNotClosed();
        }
    })
});
```

Can anyone tell me what am I missing here? Or what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

This is Sophie with Applitools. I see that you are using wdio 6, in this case, try to install @applitools/eyes-webdriverio (which is compatible with wdio 5 and 6) and remove @applitools/eyes.webdriverio (which is compatible with wdio 4).

Note that this package doesn't support the puppeteer protocol but only the webdriver protocol.

[Here is our tutorial for using eyes wdio 5 package](https://applitools.com/tutorials/webdriverio5.html)